# how do I get the response ouput from the url .download it in file,not download the code

Tags: wget, curl

My file like this with some number or id

```
 404000847307897
 404000857827460
 404001044194601
 404000835511595
 404000338418501
 404000338654003
 404000290144612
 404000344175621
 404000290144612
 404000844713523
```

this my url

```
 url= http://203.90.117.109/wds_cdma/wds.aspx?min=
```

now by using this url get the response from url and download output of the url. not the code.

example take the url and add the `min = file id` number at end of the url.

```
(http://203.90.117.109/wds_cdma/wds.aspx?min=404000847307897)
(http://203.90.117.109/wds_cdma/wds.aspx?min=404000857827460)
```

this url hit the server get the response of the url ouput below

```
 404000847307897|-101| Requested MIN not found.
 404000857827460|9225534526|2|Prepaid|2
```

finally this output store in one file.

can you do this `curl` with `awk` or `wget`?

Answer (score 1):

I can't comment yet to ask for more details on your question so I'll guess :
you have a file containing a list of numbers, you want to query an URL using each of these numbers as parameters and store the results in one file.

Using wget in a shell script :

```
#!/bin/sh
PARAMETER_FILE="/path/to/parameter/file"
URL="http://203.90.117.109/wds_cdma/wds.aspx?min="
OUTPUT_FILE="/path/to/output/file"

IFS="
"

for param in $(cat "$PARAMETER_FILE")
do
  wget "${URL}${param}" >> "$OUTPUT_FILE"
done
```

Comment: it is possible run in gnuwin32. how to run this? i am new to shell script? please tell me @ louis carrese

Comment: I did not know about gnuwin32, but I guess you could if you installed the wget package. However, you might have to do it with a .bat script so the "for" loop would not be the same. If you have to do this in Windows, I suggest you try installing [Cygwin](http://www.cygwin.com/install.html). It will allow you to run true shell scripts.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the list of file IDs is in a file called file_ids.txt.

```
for i in $(cat file_ids.txt); do 
   curl http://203.90.117.109/wds_cdma/wds.aspx?min=$i -O -s >> output.txt;
done
```

The above will create a bunch of commands like this:

```
curl http://203.90.117.109/wds_cdma/wds.aspx?min=404000847307897 -O -s >> output.txt
curl http://203.90.117.109/wds_cdma/wds.aspx?min=404000857827460 -O -s >> output.txt
curl http://203.90.117.109/wds_cdma/wds.aspx?min=404001044194601 -O -s >> output.txt
curl http://203.90.117.109/wds_cdma/wds.aspx?min=404000835511595 -O -s >> output.txt
curl http://203.90.117.109/wds_cdma/wds.aspx?min=404000338418501 -O -s >> output.txt
curl http://203.90.117.109/wds_cdma/wds.aspx?min=404000338654003 -O -s >> output.txt
curl http://203.90.117.109/wds_cdma/wds.aspx?min=404000290144612 -O -s >> output.txt
curl http://203.90.117.109/wds_cdma/wds.aspx?min=404000344175621 -O -s >> output.txt
curl http://203.90.117.109/wds_cdma/wds.aspx?min=404000290144612 -O -s >> output.txt
curl http://203.90.117.109/wds_cdma/wds.aspx?min=404000844713523 -O -s >> output.txt
```

The above loops through the list of file IDs and runs the `curl` command appending the output from the HTTP GET to the file `output.txt`. The operator `>>` takes the output from the `curl` commands and appends it to the file.